# Multiple operators in a string

Tags: r

I have some operators in a list

```
[[1]]
[1] "*"

[[2]]
[1] "-"

[[3]]
[1] "+"

[[4]]
[1] "/"

[[5]]
[1] "^"
```

I wanted to do the operations between two two datasets of same dimensions. For example, dataset1*dataset2, dataset1-dataset2, etc.  Is it possible using the strings in list?

Comment: Please provide example datasets.

Comment: Sorry, didn't knew the rules.

Comment: It's not about the rules. It's about having a clear question. As you see, you got different answers because people didn't know how your datasets look like.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is one example:

```
ops <- list("+", "-")
x <- y <- 1:10
lapply(ops, function(op) eval(parse(text = paste0("x", op, "y"))))
# [[1]]
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: `lapply(ops, do.call, args=list(x,y))` should be preferable to `eval(parse())`.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, that's indeed more elegant.